# Differentiate maven artifacts using Classifier and add them in Dependency for other applications

Tags: maven, classification, devops, pom.xml

I want to create different branches on GitHub with a different set of maven Artifacts. I found a way for that using Classifier. The issue I am facing is with the use of classifiers in the dependency section.

Suppose I have 2 components, Common and Main. Main is dependent on Common I can use Classifier in mvn command
`mvn clean install -Dclassifier=dev` 
to produce different artifacts for Common, say **common-1.2-dev.jar** and **common-1.2-sit.jar**. But while building Main which has a dependency on common, i want to somehow specify that **Main-1.2-dev.jar** should use **common-1.2-dev.jar** and **Main-1.2-sit.jar** should use **common-1.2-sit.jar**.

Is there a way to do it in the maven command, I have a lot of pom files and my team doesn't want to change them. Can I add a classifier section to all the Dependencies having a particular GroupID and artifact ID dynamically?

```
<dependency>   
   <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
   <artifactId>common</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This is what my dependency looks like right now and all the common artifacts are under the same groupID.

I think a lot of people must be doing this as every project has different branches, but I am not able to find a clear solution for this. Or am I asking for something out of the place?

Answer (score 0):

Classifiers are not meant to distinguish branches.

Your approach is not supported by Maven.

If you really want to build artifacts on different branches, you can add suffixes to the version number, like `1.2.3-somebranch-SNAPSHOT`.